# Sweave doesn't read \Sexpr{} properly

Tags: r, pdf, sweave

I am trying to make an inline code in Sweave with the function \Sexpr{}. 
Here is the sweave code I have :

```
it last 11minutes45 which \Sexpr{nrow(data)}
```

When I run the pdf with this code, I just get in my pdf: 'it last 11minutes45 which' and nothing more.

2) I have tried to add a code chunk like this :

```
<<code1, rexample = FALSE, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,message=FALSE>>=
x<-nrow(data)
@
```

and follow by

```
it last 11minutes45 which \Sexpr{x}
```

In this case I get in my pdf : 'it last 11minutes45 which' and nothing more.

3) I have tried to add a code chunk like this :

```
<<code1, rexample = FALSE, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,message=FALSE>>=
x=45000
@
```

and follow by

```
it last 11minutes45 which \Sexpr{x}
```

In this case I get in my pdf : 'it last 11minutes45 which 45000' -- which is actually what I am looking for.

4) I tried to change \ to \ or to / or // but it didn't work. I didn't download R2HTML package. I have the \usepackage{Sweave} in my first lines.

Does someone have an idea to solve my problem ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Two questions: 1, are you using Sweave or knitr?  They are two different implementations of the same idea.  I don't know all the differences in `\Sexpr` handling, but it would help in testing to know what to test.  2, what do you get if you just print `nrow(data)` in a regular code chunk?

Comment: What does the .txt file tell you, if anything?  Second, we assume you have created the object data before you call \Sexpr{}.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So yes I have created the object data. It's a dataframe with 45121 lines and 74variables to be precise. I am using Sweave. And I get NULL in my pdf when I just print nrow(data) in a regular code chunk... which is strange.... And I dont have any .txt file

Comment: StatnMap's answer would explain those results:  `data` probably isn't visible at the time you are trying to evaluate `nrow(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the object `data` **inside** the sweave document and **before** calling it? You know that when you sweave while clicking on "Compile PDF" in Rstudio, a new empty session is created (without global variables of your current session). Can you try the following example ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

There is nothing written here: \Sexpr{nrow(data)}.

<<code1, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,message=FALSE>>=
data <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
@
Result is 2 here: \Sexpr{nrow(data)}.

<<code2, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,message=FALSE>>=
x <- nrow(data)
@

Result is also 2 here: \Sexpr{x}.


\end{document}
```